# How to use elseif statement to show hidden text

Tags: if-statement, hidden, scoring, panels

New to Javascript, need some help with hidden panels.

I want the user to answer some questions in a radio button form which will have different values assigned to the checked answers. There will be 3 different options of results in hidden panels, one result will be displayed at the end depending on the score.

Link to full code and html [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2f76o36b/)

```
function results() {
            var lRisk = document.getElementById('lowRisk')
            var mRisk = document.getElementById('mediumRisk')
            var hRisk = document.getElementById('highRisk')

        if ((score >= 0) && (score =< 15)) {
            lRisk.style.display = 'inline';
        } else if ((score >= 16) && (score <= 25)) {
    mRisk.style.display = 'inline';
         } else {
        lRisk.style.display = 'inline';
        }
```

Would be very grateful for any help/advice!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display only **ONE** control based on the score, you should make all of them hidden in the start then do your conditions.

```
function results() {
        var lRisk = document.getElementById('lowRisk')
        var mRisk = document.getElementById('mediumRisk')
        var hRisk = document.getElementById('highRisk')

        lRisk.style.display = 'none';
        mRisk.style.display = 'none';
        hRisk.style.display = 'none';

        if (score >= 0 && score <= 15) {
            lRisk.style.display = 'inline';
        } else if (score >= 16 && score <= 25) {
            mRisk.style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
            hRisk.style.display = 'inline';
        }
}
```

Comment: I've set the HTML Div tags with the respective ids as style="display:none;" to avoid the HTML text from showing on the page. Does this need changing? Also I am getting an "unexpected token" error for using > when I try to run the code, is there a problem with the boolean operators I'm using?

Comment: Hi @Susan, In your first condition you're typing `score =< 15` it should be `score <= 15`

Comment: also you're missing one closing curly brace after final else `}`, check updated answer and plz don't forget to rate my answer